# Game Center in non-game apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center

I was planning to integrate game center leaderboards in this non-game app of mine. Is it wise to do so? Will I get my app rejected for integrating this game feature into something that is not a game?

I've searched and there seems to be mixed opinions/results.

Comment: I had integrated Game Center in my non game apps for at least a year. Yet now abruptly Apple rejected a new build on the ground it uses Game Center. I am really unaware if some new development has silently involved the guidelines of Apple. I asked the reviewer for the point of the guidelines forbidding Game Center in nn game apps.